# Background Image XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to incorporate a background image into my App using Xaml. I have tried various different methods but none seem to working. My code at the minute is

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cabiee;assembly=Cabiee"
         BackgroundImage="CabieBackground.jpg"
         x:Class="Cabiee.Login">

    <ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="500">


        <Entry 
            x:Name="usernameEntry" 
            Placeholder="Email"/>
        <Entry 
            x:Name="passwordEntry"
            IsPassword="true" 
            Placeholder="*********"
            Completed="PasswordEntry_Completed"/>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button 
                x:Name="BtnCustomer"
                Text="Customer"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                FontSize="30"
                Clicked="BtnCustomer_Clicked"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="BtnDriver"
                Text="Driver"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                FontSize="30"
                Clicked="BtnDriver_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Button  
                x:Name="BtnRegister"
                WidthRequest="300"
                Text="Register"
                FontSize="30"
                Clicked="BtnRegister_Clicked"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

And this what my solution explorer looks like: https://gyazo.com/0af186bbca7e8456dfb1e7b1bafcb7ad

I have CabieBackground.jpg in my Resources folder so that is displays on android but when i run the code nothing appears on the screen, it just blank

The background image was made in photoshop, the dimensions are: 640px by 1136 px with a resolution of 600 pixels/inch

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your image in drawable folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

As said in the comment, you should also ensure that the image has right properties as copy and paste make wrong properties.

Comment: Tried that but no luck ,background image isnt showing up

Comment: It could be that some of your controls above has some background color, ensure that they are transparent. But this should be enough, ensure that you have tried that and not that you think you have tried. Also check the properties of the file in the solution, if you copied the file from some other location instead of adding it the properties might not be correct.

Comment: Ah i see, I had CabieBackground.jpg in the main part and so i copied and pasted it so the properties were not the same. It works now, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can accept then the answer by clicking the accept sign if it works.